# How can I keep/retain CSS comments in the Tailwind CSS build output?

Tags: wordpress, tailwind-css, npx

I'm writing a theme for WordPress, which requires comments in the CSS file as follows:

```css
/*
Theme Name: XX
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/themes/xxtheme
Author: X team
Author URI: http://xx.org/
Description: X theme.
Version: 1.1
Text Domain: Xdomain
*/
```

Whenever I compile Tailwind CSS, the whole contents of *style.css* gets replaced. Is there an easy way to a retain part of the CSS file?
I'm using the following command to build:

```
npx tailwindcss -i css/tailwind.css -o style.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution that worked for me:

I used the PostCSS method as mentioned in the [Tailwind CSS documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss.) and then added comments at the top of the *main.css* (which is the CSS folder) file. So when I compile (using

> npm run dev

) the CSS the comments get copied to the output file. The *package.json* "scripts" tag is as follows:

> "scripts": {
> "dev": "postcss css/main.css -o style.css"   }

Answer (score 2):

Add `!` after the `/*` as shown in https://github.com/gregsullivan/_tw/blob/master/tailwind/custom/file-header.css

So the full solution will look like this.

```
/*!
Theme Name: XX
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/themes/xxtheme
Author: X team
Author URI: http://xx.org/
Description: X theme.
Version: 1.1
Text Domain: Xdomain
*/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try safelisting the comments using https://purgecss.com/safelisting.html.

I presume you are using purgecss as part of the build, but you haven’t pasted the Tailwind CSS or [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack) configuration.